# Have to Double Click to Get Data From MySQL Database Bootstrap 3 Select Library

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I have an application which is getting some data from MySQL Database by using Bootstrap 3 Group Button and Bootstrap select library as:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">4 - Select Species <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" id="specicPop">?</button></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="btn-group"  id="speciesSelect">
      <button id="allspecies" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">All Species</button>
      <button id="aquatic" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Aquatic</button>
      <button id="terrestria" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Terrestrial</button>
  </div>
    <select class="selectpicker" id="selectPicker" class="form-control" data-container="body" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="0">Select From The List</option>
 </div>
</div>
```

and the ajax is as:

```
$('.btn-group .btn').click(function(){
     $( ".selectpicker" ).selectpicker("refresh");
    $.post(
        'con/animalList.php',
        { selType : this.id },
        function(data)
        {
           $('#selectPicker').html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

the PHP part is like

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
    $resultStr.=  '<option value="0">Select From The List</option><option';
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $resultStr.=  '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['fName'].'</option>';  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $resultStr = 'Nothing found';
    }
```

Now the problem is , I have to Double click or Click Twice to load the select element with options from database. Please be informed that PHP part is working fine and I am getting correct data but I can not figure it out why the First click is not working!

Can you please let me know how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Look in your console - is the request really not being sent on a single click?

Comment: hi  ChrisWillard I checked the console but nothing showing there! I am getting the data at second click, as said but clean console!

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger tools of your current browser (usually visible through `F12` on Windows).

Then add `debugger;` to your code to see when the code gets executed.

```
$('.btn-group .btn').click(function(){
    // this will pause your execution in your browser
    // and shows you the line
    debugger;
});
```

This way, you will see if the first click is realy not triggering.
If it is not, you might have an error somewhere different in your code.

Do you have other JS code that might break your code?

Comment: Hi luke thanks fir reply actually the debugger works and I just figure it out that the Bootstrap Select is causing the issue after removing the  .selectpicker from the select element ever thing works fine!

Comment: Glad it helped you out!